# Pytorch Training; "Runtime Error:PyTorch and torchvision versions are incompatible ..."

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, torchvision

**SOLUTION at the bottom!**

**I want to do Object Detection with this tutorial:**

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-your-own-object-detector-pytorch-vs-tensorflow-and-how-to-even-get-started-1d314691d4ae

**Although I have compatible versions of Pytorch, Torchvision and Cuda:**

`conda list torch` gives me:
[image]

**I get the following RunTime Error at the bottom:**

> **RuntimeError**: Couldn't load custom C++ ops. This can happen if your
> **PyTorch and torchvision versions are incompatible**, or if you had
> errors while compiling torchvision from source. For further
> information on the compatible versions, check
> https://github.com/pytorch/vision#installation for the compatibility
> matrix. Please check your PyTorch version with torch__version__ and
> your torchvision version with torchvision__version__ and verify if
> they are compatible, and if not please reinstall torchvision so that
> it matches your PyTorch install.

**when running:**

```
num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    
    train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)#.to_fp16()
    
    lr_scheduler.step()
    
    evaluate(model, data_loader_test, device=device)
```

**Is it really an error resulting from incompatibility of pytorch and torchvision?**

Thank you very much.

**SOLUTION:**

I imported torchvision from the wrong directory. I found out using following:

```
import torchvision
print(torchvision.__path__)
```

Comment: Could you show the exact result of `conda list torch` (or equivalent if you installed with `pip`)?

Comment: @Ivan.I just edited the list above. Thank you.
I'm using Jupyter Notebook. Also, the notebook won't give me the version of torchvision. 'AttributeError: module 'torchvision' has no attribute 'version' –