# AttributeError: module 'torchvision' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, object-detection, torchvision

**I want to do Object Detection with this tutorial:**

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-your-own-object-detector-pytorch-vs-tensorflow-and-how-to-even-get-started-1d314691d4ae

I'm using Windows, conda environment, installed Pytorch-1.7.1, Torchvision-0.8.2, Cuda-Toolkit-11.0 > all compatible.

`conda list torch` gives me:
[image]

But, when asking for the torchvision version in Jupyter Notebook, I get:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-f7c0e30812bc> in <module>
      1 import torchvision
----> 2 torchvision.__version__

AttributeError: module 'torchvision' has no attribute '__version__'
```

I have to know if my notebook uses torchvision 0.8.2 or another version.
I need this info because later a Error relating to incompatibility of Pytorch and Torchvision shows up. [Pytorch Training; "Runtime Error:PyTorch and torchvision versions are incompatible ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68520274/15573757)

Comment: Is it possible you created a file in your current working directory named `torchvision.py`?  What does it show if you `import torchvision; print(torchvision)`.

Comment: - `import torchvision; print (torchvision)` gives `<module 'torchvision' (namespace)>
`

- No `torchvision.py` file in directory. But I am using the Pytorch/vision repository https://github.com/pytorch/vision which has a torchvision folder

Comment: I thought you said you installed torchvision with conda.  Why, then, are you working out of the repository?  It looks like you somehow have multiple `torchvision` directories on your python path, which Python is interpreting as a namespace package.  What does `print(torchvision.__path__)` show?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Iguananaut!

I imported torchvision from the wrong directory.

This was the right torchvision path:

```
<module 'torchvision' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/__init__.py'>
['/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision']
```